# For a multi-class classification problem, how to transform the target variable to a form that is usable by sklearn algorithms?

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, encoding

I recently tried to create a model for predicting what class a sample belongs to out of 160 possible classes. These classes of the target variable are just simple strings describing workouts like "Push-ups", "Sit-ups" etc. I used sklearn's method LabelEncoder to transform the target variable, and it assigned every class a number between 0 and 159. I know that the reason why we are supposed to do one-hot encoding for categorical *features* is to avoid telling an algorithm something nonsensical like "blue is greater than red". My question then becomes, doesn't LabelEncoder tell the sklearn algorithm that "push-ups" is less than or greater than "sit-ups" if both of them are assigned distinct numbers between 0-159? Why or why not? This feels like a very stupid question, but I had real trouble finding an answer anywhere online.

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: The answer from @I_Play_With_Data that I accepted two weeks after I posted this question did end up solving my problem, even if the answer was a bit on the "just google it" side of things. Thinking of it as a "slot" for each category helped me - the number isn't used as a scalar value or something like that. From there, just make sure you know the mapping of feature name to the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site! Do a google search for "one hot encoding" and all will become clear.

In a nutshell, don't think of it as numbers "assigned" of 0-159. It's more about a "slot" for each category and using one hot encoding to let the algorithm know which slot a particular record belongs to.